# Magento 2: 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException)

Tags: magento, exception, composer-php

I installed a Magento extension called Mageplaza Productslider using a manual method (copy files to app/code). This didn't look to work, so I installed the extension using composer:

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider)
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I still couldn't see the extension on any page so I decided to uninstall. To do this I deleted the Mageplaza folder from app/code and ran the following code to uninstall the Mageplaza extension and core:

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content
```

I now have the following error on my Magento 2 product pages on the frontend and when I try to edit products in the admin panel.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class 
Mageplaza\Productslider\Model\Slider\Source\FeaturedProducts does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class 
Mageplaza\Productslider\Model\Slider\Source\FeaturedProducts does not exist
```

To see full error, please see (if links aren't allowed please remove??):

```
https://www.canvaspro.com.au/horse-canvas.html
```

I have undertaken the following to attempt to fix the error:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* vendor

composer install

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

As I have deleted the var and vendor folders, how come after composer install Magento is still calling for these files under app/code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dipesh, your advice helped but did not resolve the problem, for those with a similar issue please see how I fixed this.

As I did not install this module using composer, trying to use composer to uninstall throws the following error:

php bin/magento module:uninstall Mageplaza_Productslider
Mageplaza_Productslider is not an installed composer package

The module must be uninstalled manually, this involves editing the database, follow steps below:

- Disable the module: php bin/magento module:disable Mageplaza_Productslider --clear-static-content
- Note in this case, Mageplaza_Core also needs to be disabled and removed
- Delete the Module folder from app\code\
- Open your database and browse to table setup_module, and delete Mageplaza_Productslider and Mageplaza_Core rows
- Open database table eav_attribute. Mageplaza_Productslider was entered in here as a "featured product" and this was causing my error. Delete the row in this table.
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:flush

After the above, I also ran:

- rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* vendor
- composer install
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- I did not deploy static content as in developer mode, if you're not in developer mode then deploy static content: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- Set file permissions:

find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;

find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;

This worked for me... hope it can possibly help some others!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**composer remove  mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider**

php bin/magento cache:clean,
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f